# How to plug existing Observables into Alpine.js (liveQuery from Dexie.js)

Tags: alpine.js, dexie

How are existing reactive observables connected to Alpine.js?

The [Dexie.js website](https://dexie.org/docs/liveQuery()) lists a few examples with React and Svelte but how would I use [Dexie.js liveQuery](https://dexie.org/docs/liveQuery()) with Alpine.js? Is it as simple as passing the variable to `x-data`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass directly a `liveQuery` object to an Alpine.js property because it will lose reactivity. We need to create a small wrapper that updates Alpine.js data when a `liveQuery` returns new data. Here I provide a small example that uses a `products` table, the Alpine.js component just lists the products and there's a small form that can add new products to the DB.

Example database definition in `db.js`:

```
import Dexie from 'dexie'

export const db = new Dexie('myDatabase')
db.version(1).stores({
  products: '++id, name, color',
})
```

In `main.js` we make `db` and `liveQuery` global:

```
import Alpine from 'alpinejs'

import { liveQuery } from "dexie"
window.liveQuery = liveQuery

import { db } from './db'
window.db = db

window.Alpine = Alpine
window.Alpine.start()
```

The example Alpine.js component:

```
<div x-data="productsComponent">
  <div>
    <input type="text" x-model="name" placeholder="Name" />
    <input type="text" x-model="color" placeholder="Color" />
    <button @click="add">Add product</button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h2>Products</h2>
    <template x-for="p in products">
      <div x-text="`ID: ${p.id} Name: ${p.name} Color: ${p.color}`"></div>
    </template>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
  Alpine.data('productsComponent', () => ({
    products: [],
    name: '',
    color: '',

    observe(dataName, observable) {
      const subscription = observable.subscribe({
        next: val => {this[dataName] = val}
      })
    },

    init() {
      this.observe('products', liveQuery(() => db.products.toArray()))
    },

    async add() {
      const id = await db.products.add({
        name: this.name,
        color: this.color,
      })
      this.name = ''
      this.color = ''
    }
  }))
})
</script>
```

In the `observe` method we subscribe the specific `liveQuery` event and update the Alpine.js data when it changes.